# ASP.NET MVC - After HTML append with Jquery the DropDownList value comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two dropdownlist and when I change the value of the first one with refreshes the value of the second one with the following code:

```
 function FillBooks(val) {
            $("#ddl_dep").attr("class", "form-group");
            $("#Help1").css("visibility", "hidden");
            var CategoryId = val;
            //console.log(CategoryId);
            console.log(CategoryId)
            $("#DDL_TIPO").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTipo", "Tickets")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { value: CategoryId },
                success: function (data) {
                    var markup = "<option value='0'>Selecione um Tipo</option>";
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        markup += "<option value=" + data[x].value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#DDL_TIPO").html(markup).show();

                }
            });

        }
```

P.S - The data comes from the controller which is not relevant for the exemple that I am showing.

After this when I try to get the value of the Second dropdownlist it comes as undefined.

I tested before this jquery code and it gives me the value of the dropdownlist, it just doesn't give when I get this function to work on it.

Comment: how and where and when are you trying to get the value of the second dropdown? The context for your problem is unclear. Is it possible the value is not defined because after you refresh the dropdown there is no longer any currently selected option? You may have to wait for the user to select something? I'm only guessing because, like I mentioned, you haven't given us the full situation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<script>  
        function FillBooks(val)  
    {  

                $("#ddl_dep").attr("class", "form-group");
                $("#Help1").css("visibility", "hidden");
                var CategoryId = val;
                //console.log(CategoryId);
                console.log(CategoryId) 
            $.ajax  
            ({  
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTipo", "Tickets")',
                type: 'POST',  
                datatype: 'application/json',  
                contentType: 'application/json',  
                data: { value: CategoryId },  
                success: function(result)  
              {  
                    $("#DDL_TIPO").html("");  
                    $.each($.parseJSON(result), function(i, tipo)  
                    {  
                        $("#DDL_TIPO").append($('<option</option>').val(tipo.Value).html(tipo.Text))  
                    })  

                },  
                error: function()  
                {  
                    alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..")  
                },  
            });  
        }  
    </script>
```